# Grabbing traffic from COM

Tags: assembly, serial-port, pascal

I need to grab traffic from COM port under **MS-DOS**.

I found program **ComSpy** (which must grab data from COM port and send to prn, do it in TSR), run it, run **prn2file.exe** and run analyzed program, but it did not logging.

Is it possible to write a memory-resident program (**MS-DOS**) to get all traffic from COM port and log to file, but without interfering with other program (which communicate with com port(work with com by interrupts))?

Comment: You are going to have to break into a museum to find a tool like that.  Neither shopping questions nor time machine purchases are on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is possible.  Just write a TSR that hooks the COM interrupts and does the appropriate dos entry monitoring.  Don't use the BIOS/DOS com read/write routines as they're terribly slow.  Not a big deal, a zillion books were written about it back in the day, you should be able to google some up.  :-)

Comment: But, if I hook the COM interrupt, and read byte from receiver, analyzed program don't get it.

Comment: Better post up some code.  Without that, all I can say is "obviously you're not doing it quite right".  :-)

Comment: I don't think your answer is true. Yes, you can install your own serial port ISR, in a TSR. However two serial port ISRs cannot both be active: you may chain ISRs for such services as the timer tick or multiplex interrupt ... but serial port ISRs also use IN and OUT to read and write serial port data, and you can't have two ISRs both using IN to read the same data (the serial port hardware will only return the same data once). What/all you can do is install a new INT 14h service (if the software you're hooking is willing to read from the BIOS API instead of using its own ISR).